# Why in J 0%0 is defined, but _%_ gives a NaN error?

Tags: nan, j

I J, `0%0` ([zero divided by zero](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/zero.htm)) gives 0 as an answer. However, `_%_` (infinity divided by infinity) gives a NaN error? Why isn't it defined, while `0%0` is?

Comment: +1 Sheesh, at the very least it could give `_.`, undetermined.

Comment: Both should give `NaN` (or `_.`). It is practical, however, to define `0%0` as `0`; there are no similar reasons to do so for `_%_`. See [Essays/Indeterminate](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Indeterminate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comment from Eelvex gives the answer. infinity over infinity is indeterminate. The indeterminate symbol in J is `_.`. However, this exists only to take care of data coming from external source, and J sentences shouldn't gives `_.` as an answer.

If 0 over 0 is defined as 0, this is because it has some practical uses. There are no such practical uses for infinity over infinity.

Answer (score 1):

"Although zero divided by zero is indeterminate, it is desirable to provide a fixed quotient for it in a programming environment, in order to reduce the number of circumstances when it is necessary to interrupt the execution of a problem." This is the explanation by E. E. McDonnell from the paper [Zero Divided by Zero](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/zero.htm).

A problem with [Infinity](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d030.htm) is that it is not a value, but it is treated as a value. If Infinity were a value then `_%_` would be One, as is the typical case where a number is divided by itself. (J implements 0%0 as an exception to that pattern.) My intuition is that J would be better were `_%_` computed as resolving to One, but it isn't. So, while I cannot give an answer to your question, I propose that no answer is available from mathematics, nor is one to be found in J documentation or commentary.